# SQL Query Multiple Joins

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Revised. My SQL is limited, so really appreciate your help. In one hit, I want to query by ID ($ga_id) two tables each with an inner join to another table (tables have exactly the same columns and the parent tables have no relationship to each other).

I can successfully query the net_5_postmeta table as follows

```
SELECT p.*
FROM net_5_postmeta AS pm
INNER JOIN net_5_posts AS p ON pm.meta_value=p.ID 
WHERE pm.post_id = $ga_id
AND pm.meta_key = '_thumbnail_id' 
ORDER BY p.post_date DESC 
LIMIT 4
```

but I want to query the net_5_postmeta table and the net_7_postmeta table (they have the same columns), I think it needs to be something along the lines of...

```
SELECT p.*
FROM net_5_postmeta, net_7_postmeta AS pm
INNER JOIN net_5_posts AS p ON pm.meta_value=p.ID
INNER JOIN net_7_posts AS p ON pm.meta_value=p.ID 
WHERE pm.post_id = $ga_id
AND pm.meta_key = '_thumbnail_id' 
ORDER BY p.post_date DESC 
LIMIT 4
```

Comment: This is pretty complex to answer as is.  If I can make a suggestion: Try just showing 1) the table descriptions 2) The desired output.  I think you might get more responses that way as the current question length is a bit long.  Hope this help you get better replies.

Comment: At minimum, we don't need the PHP code.  And what's the (logical, conceptual) connection between the `net_5_` and `net_7_` tables?

Comment: great tip Michael, I did my best to simplify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you say that parent tables have no relationship i can only assume that you want to treat *5* and *7* tables as if they were the same. You should use `union all` to bring their data together and then do ORDER BY/LIMIT.

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
  SELECT p.*
  FROM net_5_postmeta AS pm
  INNER JOIN net_5_posts AS p ON pm.meta_value=p.ID 
  WHERE pm.post_id = $ga_id
  AND pm.meta_key = '_thumbnail_id' 

  UNION ALL

  SELECT p.*
  FROM net_7_postmeta AS pm
  INNER JOIN net_7_posts AS p ON pm.meta_value=p.ID 
  WHERE pm.post_id = $ga_id
  AND pm.meta_key = '_thumbnail_id' 
) united
ORDER BY united.post_date DESC 
LIMIT 4
```